# Find & Replace Text in Incoming Emails

Tags: vba, replace, outlook

I am trying to replace certain text in incoming e-mails.

I found several scripts but these work on outgoing / creating e-mails.

***CURRENT WORKING CODE*** (Thanks to Larry):

```
Sub testing(MyMail As MailItem)
    MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "TESTING", "TESTINGTESTING")
    MyMail.Save
End Sub
```

This Outlook Session code:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

    Dim mail As MailItem

    Set mail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.GetFirst
    If mail.Class = olMail Then 'It should be
        'change subject
        mail.Subject = "TESTING"
        'replace body text
        If mail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
            mail.HTMLBody = Replace(mail.HTMLBody, "TESTING", "TESTINGTESTING")
        Else
            mail.Body = Replace(mail.Body, "SEARCHTEXT", "REPLACETEXT")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for processing emails in inbox.

```
Sub testing()
    Dim mail As MailItem
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder

    Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    For Each mail In Inbox.Items
        'change subject
        mail.Subject = "TESTING"
        'replace body text
        If mail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
            mail.HTMLBody = Replace(mail.HTMLBody, "TESTING", "TESTINGTESTING")
        Else
            mail.Body = Replace(mail.Body, "SEARCHTEXT", "REPLACETEXT")
        End If
    Next mail
End Sub
```

Use below code if you want the macro to apply whenever there is a new mail.

Put the code inside the `ThisOutlookSession` Module.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    Dim newMail As MailItem

    Set newMail = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.GetFirst

    newMail.HTMLBody = Replace(newMail.HTMLBody, "TESTING", "TESTINGTESTING")
End Sub
```

This code snippet can be used in "Run a Script" in "Rules".

```
Sub testing(MyMail As MailItem)
    MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "TESTING", "TESTINGTESTING")
    MyMail.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick respondse Larry,
But How can I actually replace the text in the e-mail now?
Can I just add "Item.Body = Replace(Item.Body, "some text", "some replacement text")" which i found somewhere?

I really suck at this stuff :P

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I'm not so sure about the formatting if the changes are made to Body, maybe you can try on HTMLBody (mail.HTMLBody)

Comment: Sorry about the mess, i can't answer my own question yet.
Sub testing(MyMail As MailItem)
Dim mail As MailItem
Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) For Each mail In Inbox.Items 'change subject mail.Subject = "TESTING" Item.Body = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, "Test 123", "It's Working!") Next mail End Sub

I'm using this atm as my code, but it doesn't seem to replace the text, it does however change the subject of the e-mail.
Is this correct? (also i changed the sub testing part, because it didn't show up in the script list).
Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Larry. I REALLY apreciate you helping me with this problem, i've been stuck searching for over a week. The code you gave me seems to be working if I run it manually but not when a e-mail comes in my mailbox. Should I change anything? I've updates the code in my question at the top.

Comment: Ok, so it works manually now,   see my 2nd code snippet for the effect you want

Comment: It's not working yet :(  Uploaded an image with the error. btw if it helps, i'm using Outlook 2007.

Comment: Hi, please copy my latest 2nd code snippet and try it again. If you still get error, a debug tech. is "At the highlighted line" , right click "mail" --> Add to watch and snapshot.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the option you are referring to.. :( You mean right click the mail.Class thing and then add it? If I do this i'm getting the following options: (Turn on/off some stuff), (Object overview), (Add a check),(Run till cursor),(setup next instruction), (View next instruction) and definition.  Using a dutch version so it's really annoying to find stuff :S

Comment: I mean highlight "mail" and right click "add to watch"   btw. Have u tried my updated code?

Comment: Sigh, for some reason the error is showing again and I haven't changed anything. The only thing i did was restart Outlook. Could you please help me again? You wanted me to highlight the "mail" and choose add to watch. But that option isn't showing up for me, or i'm translating wrong. Is it like add a check? it called "Controle Toevoegen" in Dutch.

Comment: That's alright, I still got a few days before I need to finish this.
Thank you for the help so far and have a nice day :)

Comment: @Kris Hi, can you update in the question the current code you have.
And we can continue discussion in http://us5.chatzy.com/46938623689463

Comment: Hi, @Kris , I can think of one possible reason, maybe "mail" is a keyword in outlook? try changing it into myMail 

Also , the 3rd snippet can be used in "Run in script" give it a try too.

Comment: Hi, I just tried the 3rd snippet and I got the following error:  "Run-time error 424 - Object required"

Comment: sorry, my mistake, should be MyMail instead of NewMail, updating the 3rd snippet now

Comment: The code seems to be working now, but if I add it as a rule on all incoming messages it doesn't seem to do anything, no errors either. If I run it manually it does what it's intended to do.

Comment: ONE line i missed, seems we need to save the change. see edit

Comment: @Kris Don't forget to accept the answer after you verify it's correct

Comment: will do :) I just had one more question if you don't mind.
Is it possible to change every ^p with ^l? (the carriage returns stuff) because that doesn't seem to work at the moment.

Comment: I am sure it's possible, if it's a unprintable character, then you need to use chr() and look up the values in ASCII table, you should raise another SO question with examples

Comment: Alright, thanks again for all your hard work. would've never been able to do this without your help :) going to accept your answer now.